# Expected response code 250 but got an empty response swift_transportexception Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses, swiftmailer

I am using Amazon SES for sending emails from PHP application through Swift Mailer. I am searching on google from 3 4 days but was unable to find any solution. I tried every possible solution available on Internet but still, my issue is not resolved. Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue?
This happens intermittently but appears to cause all our mails to stop sending once the initial error occurs - restarting the queue worker fixes it but inevitably the problem re-occurs intermittently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem.